# nosuchelementexception in calling a dynamic web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I am trying to call a web service dynamically, I don't have any problem in calling a method  with input  parameters , but when I use a method without arguments, I got nosuchelementexception error ,My source code is described below:

I have an interface :

```
public interface SmsParam extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public String getSmsIncomePackServices()  throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public String getCustMobileNo(Integer intCustId)  throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

and I use below code for calling getSmsIncomePackServices method:

```
String  UrlString = " ?wsdl";
String nameSpaceUri = " ";
String serviceName = " ";
String portName = "coreBankingSMSWebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint";//"inactiveMobileSMSHttpSoap11Endpoint";



ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();

Service helloService = serviceFactory.createService(helloWsdlUrl, new QName(nameSpaceUri, serviceName));

SmsParam myProxy = (SmsParam)helloService.getPort(
                                    new QName(nameSpaceUri, portName),
                                    SmsParam.class);


myProxy.getCustMobileNo(12); //Runs successfuly
myProxy.getSmsFreePackServices();//I got nosuchelementexception  error
```

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand how the code compiled... There is no `getSmsFreePackServices()` method defined in your interface SmsParam.

Your SmsParam  contains `getSmsIncomePackServices` and `getCustMobileNo` methods only